# Load dynamic html jQuery changing GET script path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apache, lumen

I'm trying to load HTML from URL dynamically. I use this code:

```
    LoadingSpinner.open();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Views/MyView',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response){
            //This line trigger the error
            $('#MyDiv').html(response.replaceAll('\n', ''));
            LoadingSpinner.close();
        },
        error: function(){
            LoadingSpinner.close();
            ModalService.abrirModalError('Error de conexion', 'Ha ocurrido un error obteniendo la página');
        }
    });
```

When I do click in one element, I request by GET MyView, this works fine, but when I go to render this view to my page using jQuery inside "MyDiv" with $('#MyDiv').html(...) the script tag inside that HTML fails. The HTML containing my script tag is this:

```
    <script src="/NuevoERP/includes/js/gestion/productos/detailFamilia.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<h2>Detalle de la familia {{$familia->desc_nombre}}</h2> 
<div class="col-lg-12 m-t-5">

    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label>Categoria de la familia: <span class="fontNormal">{{$familia->categoriaFamilia->desc_nombre}}</span></label>
        <label>Referencia: <span class="fontNormal">{{$familia->code_referencia}}</span></label>
        <label>Nombre: <span class="fontNormal">{{$familia->desc_nombre}}</span></label>
        <?php if ($familia->familiaPadre != null) : ?>
            <label>Familia padre: <span class="fontNormal">{{$familia->familiaPadre->desc_nombre}}</span></label>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying include the javascript file with src="/NuevoERP/includes/js/gestion/productos/detailFamilia.js", but the Browser Console show me that is trying to load the file from " http://localhost:8080/NuevoERP/http://localhost:8080/NuevoERP/includes/js/gestion/productos/detailProductoServicio.js", that's incorrect, the correct is  "http://localhost:8080/NuevoERP/includes/js/gestion/productos/detailProductoServicio.js"

I'm using Apache with Lumen Framework, my application is in other path that my DocumentRoot, I'm Using an Alias, that's my apache.conf:

```
    #
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:8080

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:8080>    
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/HDD/NetBeansProjects/AntiguoERP/Desarrollo/ERP"       
    ServerName localhost    
    Alias /NuevoERP "/Volumes/HDD/NetBeansProjects/BaymaSalt/ERPBaymaSalt/public"
    <Directory "/Volumes/HDD/NetBeansProjects/BaymaSalt/ERPBaymaSalt/public">                            
        AllowOverride All        
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the .htaccess of my Lumen index.php("/Volumes/HDD/NetBeansProjects/BaymaSalt/ERPBaymaSalt/public") is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /NuevoERP/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I couldn't use two different VirtualHost, I Need one Host with my root path (http://localhost:8080) with php 5.0 and my Alias /NuevoERP with php 7.0

Comment: Provide an [mcve] not [a picture of errors](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) or [code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Question edited , thanks ;)

Comment: So are there two issues? The `$('#MyDiv').html(response.replaceAll('\n', ''));` and `http://localhost:8080/NuevoERP/http://localhost:8080/NuevoERP/`?

Comment: "This line trigger the error" What's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct, the problem was that a partner had created an AJAX request interceptor and modified the URL at run time, created it without saying anything and this was modifying the request of the web browser to get the javascript file